# Return efficiently all occurrences for substring in Pandas Python DataFrame (large tables)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I obtain the values that I am searching for in a dataframe using str.contains?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ['Philip', 'Jana', 'Kate', 'John K.', 'Jonhatan'],
                   "City": ['NewYork', 'New jearsey', 'Mexico City', 'Lisbon', 'Bahia'],
                   "Language": ['English', 'english', 'Spanish, Dutch, German', 'Spanish and English', 'Portuguese, English'],
                    "Years": [24, 27, 29, 40, 61] })

search = 'english'
mask = np.column_stack([df[col].astype(str).str.contains(search, flags=re.I) for col in df.columns]).nonzero()

df.where(mask)
```

Returns:

[image]

Ideally I would like to have the following inside a single series:

```
pd.Series(['English', 'english', 'Spanish and English', 'Portuguese, English'])
```

**EDIT**: The assumption is that I don't know where is the value located within the dataframe. Also I want to use str.contains because of ability to use regex.

Comment: `df.where(mask).stack()`.

Answer (score 1):

Make simple things simple. Iterate over the 'Language' column items and filter out all which contain the word 'english' as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ['Philip', 'Jana', 'Kate', 'John K.', 'Jonhatan'],
                   "City": ['NewYork', 'New jearsey', 'Mexico City', 'Lisbon', 'Bahia'],
                   "Language": ['English', 'english', 'Spanish, Dutch, German', 'Spanish and English', 'Portuguese, English'],
                    "Years": [24, 27, 29, 40, 61] })
print(df)
print(' --- ')
ds = pd.Series( [ entry for entry in df['Language'] if 'english' in  entry.lower() ] )
print(ds)
```

In case the column name is not known you have to iterate over all items in the pandas dataframe and filter out all strings you can find. I have modified the `df` so that you can see it will find also 'Jana English' from the "Name" column:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name":     ['Philip', 'Jana English', 'Kate', 'John K.', 'Jonhatan'],
                   "City":     ['NewYork', 'New jearsey', 'Mexico City', 'Lisbon', 'Bahia'],
                   "Language": ['English', 'english', 'Spanish, Dutch, German', 'Spanish and English', 'Portuguese, English'],
                    "Years":   [24, 27, 29, 40, 61] })
print(df)
print(' --- ')
ds = []
for column in df.columns:
   ds.extend([ entry for entry in df[column] 
       if isinstance(entry, str) and 'english' in  entry.lower()])
ds = pd.Series(ds)
print(ds)
```

Here the output of above code:

```
           Name         City                Language  Years
0        Philip      NewYork                 English     24
1  Jana English  New jearsey                 english     27
2          Kate  Mexico City  Spanish, Dutch, German     29
3       John K.       Lisbon     Spanish and English     40
4      Jonhatan        Bahia     Portuguese, English     61
 --- 
0           Jana English
1                English
2                english
3    Spanish and English
4    Portuguese, English
dtype: object
```

If speed is an issue list comprehension could be faster than Python loop so check it out:

```
Rows, Cols = df.shape
ds = pd.Series( [item for item in [ 
        df.iloc[row,col] for col in range(Cols) for row in range(Rows) ] 
        if isinstance(item, str) and 'english' in item.lower()] )
```

Probably even faster then this above should be be:

```
dsl = []
def f(e):
    global dsl
    if isinstance(e, str) and 'english' in e.lower(): dsl.append(e) 
df.applymap(f)
ds = pd.Series(dsl)
print(ds)
```

and if this is still not fast enough ... why not use directly the CSV text and search in the text using regular expressions?

Comment: Let's assume you don't know where it is located. You don't know the column. You just know what you want to find.

Comment: See my updated answer covering this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
regex = 'english'
ps = pd.Series(item for item in df.values.reshape(-1) 
               if re.search(regex, str(item), flags=re.I))
print(ps)
```

gives:

```
0                English
1           Jana English
2                english
3    Spanish and English
4    Portuguese, English
```

for

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name":     ['Philip', 'Jana English', 'Kate', 'John K.', 'Jonhatan'],
                   "City":     ['NewYork', 'New jearsey', 'Mexico City', 'Lisbon', 'Bahia'],
                   "Language": ['English', 'english', 'Spanish, Dutch, German', 'Spanish and English', 'Portuguese, English'],
                    "Years":   [24, 27, 29, 40, 61] })
```

or if you insist on using `str.contains()` *(but be aware that this version will be 15x times slower than the other one)*:

```
ps = pd.concat([df[col].where(
       df[col].astype(str).str.contains(regex, flags=re.I)).dropna() 
       for col in df.columns])
print(ps)
```

giving:

```
1           Jana English
0                English
1                english
3    Spanish and English
4    Portuguese, English
```